# Does nginx Ingress controller require a Service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#why-endpoints-and-not-services

Currently, my setup is pretty standard in that I have a deployment, a ClusterIP service, and an Ingress.

I also use nginx Ingress controller and my default understanding is that you need a service to make your pods accessible within a cluster, and and Ingress to route traffic outside of the cluster to your service.

The documentation above, however, says that a service is not used and pods are accessed via the Endpoints API.

This is a bit confusing in that I don't understand whether this means I don't even need to create a Service.

Thanks!

I have always had both services and ingresses so it feels a bit risky to experiment without a proper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The NGINX Ingress controller simplifies pod exposure by directly routing traffic to pods without requiring a Service. This eliminates the need to create a Service for each pod.

Instead, the Ingress controller monitors Ingress objects and configures itself to forward client requests to the relevant pods within the cluster.

Essentially, the Ingress controller acts as a traffic router for incoming requests, directing them to the appropriate pods, while the application's web-server handles the actual request processing. This approach streamlines application exposure to end-users outside the cluster network.